# Do static memory addresses change with different computers?

Tags: java, c++, memory, memory-address, cheat-engine

I have been messing with cheat engine and I am trying to learn how to make cheats(for really basic and simple video games). So far I understand that there is static and dynamic memory and to get to the static you have to do all this weird pointer stuff. I am a little confused because I know there are things out there like aim bots that work on different computers. Are static memory addresses all the same regardless of computer? If not, can someone tell me how that works?
ps. Can I change memory directly using Java?

Comment: There are no guarantees that the address of static variables will persist upon different launches on same computer.

Comment: And Java is not rhe best choiche for hacking with phisical memory

Comment: "Are static memory addresses all the same regardless of computer?" - Today, we use virtual memory which allows processes to have the same subjective memory layout on different machines and in different instances.

Comment: "you have to do all this weird pointer stuff" - You may be heading in the wrong direction with your plans concerning the use of Java.

Comment: I was just wondering if java would work but I can use c++ too.

Answer (score 0):

The codes stay same if they are static (in most cases)